# Get Query String URL Path in PHP with $_SERVER

Tags: php, url, query-string

I have a form that has a "*textarea*" where I'm looking to capture the full URL of the page the user is on. Once this form is submitted I'm looking to include the full URL into an email that goes out.

However, the problem I keep running into is that the string gets cut off at the first "**&**" in the URL string.

**Here is an example URL string:**

`example.com/folder/results.php?lat=38.10591&lng=-51.556916898&zipcode=32827&countryIso=US`

**Here is what I have tried:**

```
<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $url; ?>
```

**I've also tried:**

```
<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; echo $url; ?>
```

Neither one worked to include the full URL... Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: $url = 'www.mysite.com/category/subcategory?myqueryhash';
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY); # output "myqueryhash"

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is correct. Perhaps some other piece of code is munging it?

Comment: parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);    It's Automatically Create Var. which u pass in url parameter .. You have to just use it   .

Comment: Assuming the user entered http://example.com/?name=antivinegar    ....  So   <?php
echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]) . '!';
?>     will Give Output ::     Hello antivinegar

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar would this work with a long URL string such as the one provided up above? I need to keep the full URL intact and not broken... It has to pass into an email, but it's breaking at the first "&"

Comment: okk  But try this ..  
<?php $url= basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); echo $url; ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you send your form's POST request to this url :

```
example.com/folder/results.phplat=38.10591&lng=-51.556916898&zipcode=32827&countryIso=US
```

I think your problem is that you are logging the url of the url of the file processing the form.  Have you tried storing the content of this into an hidden field of your form?

```
<?php $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $url; ?>
```

Comment: When I use the form as a "POST" it won't pass the data... However, when I use it as a "GET" the data passes. 

If I were to use it as a "hidden" field I wouldn't be able to pass it in the body of an email.. no?

Comment: <?php $url= 
basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  echo $url; ?>

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar I tried your suggestion... I had to include the domain in-front of the code `example.com/<?php $url= basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); echo $url; ?>` to get it to function. However, when the email came in the URL was still broke at the first "**&**" of the query string.

Comment: The content of an hidden field will be accessible by it's name on the php side. $_GET['hiddenFieldName'];

But now you've got to see it on the page and you seem to only have trouble with the email. Does it break before or after the "&" ? Have you tried escaping it? Either by replacing it with \& or encoding it with htmlentities()

Comment: @Lou your "hidden" field worked with one of the tests... it helped solve the fact that I had an extra middle page that was throwing off the passing of the data. After performing the "hidden" field test it fixed the issue. thx!